# Авторизация на сайте через android приложение с помощью js-скриптов

Tags: javascript, android

Есть такой код

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value = 45;");
```

С помощью него я пытаюсь ввести значение в поле логина, но это работает только с цифровыми значениями.

Если я пытаюсь ввести строковое значение, то просто открывается новое окно с этим значением

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы бы хоть показали как присваиваете строку - может про кавычки забываете?

Comment: webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value = 'testtest';"); Я перепробовал все варианты, и с кавычками и с апострофами, результат один

Comment: Может так и должно быть? Надо код страницы видеть, что бы понимать, что там происходит.

Comment: webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value = 'name';" +
                       "document.getElementById('password').value = 'password';" +
                       "login();");  в общем это похоже какая-то особенность вебвью, закинул в один реквест сразу все нужные мне параметры и вызвал логин() все отработало